# Visual Studio Indent Using Spaces never saves the setting

Tags: visual-studio-code

So the standard setting seems to be 1 tab equals 2 spaces for indentation. I always change that to 4 spaces, [you can see that here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2hZG5.png)
. But that setting never seems to save. When I work with Visual Studio on the next day, its back to 2. May it be that the Prettier Extension is overwriting something?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem: The setting "Editor: Detect Indentation" has to be turned off. Also you can go to Prettier's Settings and set the Indentation to 4 Spaces too, so when autoformatting, the indentation of 4 instead of 2 spaces is kept.